# How do I get JavaFX to run with JGrasp?

Tags: javafx, download, installation, jgrasp

I have tried this numerous times with errors trying to find JavaFX package. Yes, I tried messing around with the environment variables, but it didn't help. I'm lost. The oracle website gives instructions, but when I click on the link, it says the page has moved and I can't follow the instructions given. And every time I look for advice from the forums, somebody online somewhere gives the cop-out answer of "use netbeans". No. I'm not going to use netbeans. I want to use JavaFX on JGrasp. Sorry...

Comment: I don't know jGrasp, but what JDK version are you using? If it is an old version ( < JDK 8) you need to include the jfxrt.jar file in the classpath: you will find that in `JDK_HOME/jre/lib`.

Comment: This is also a little strange. I go to the command prompt and type in "java -version" and it says version 8 update 25. But I have two program files folders: inside Program Files > Java > there is jdk1.7.0_21, jdk1.8.0_05, jdk1.8.0_25, jre1.8.0_25, jre7... inside Program Files (x86) > Java > jre1.8.0_25, and jre7. It's a cluster-f**k in there, and I'm wondering if that's also messing with things.

Comment: Not really; I have several JDKs installed. Can you configure your jGrasp JavaFX project to use jdk1.8.0_25?

Comment: I believe jGrasp is already using version 8 because when I click the API link in the help menu, it takes me to the version 8 API.

Comment: I downloaded it and tried it out: it worked fine for me. I didn't really have much clue what I was doing with jGrasp; I just created a test project, create a new Java file, and typed in a "Hello World" application subclass. I couldn't figure out how to get jGrasp to automatically add the imports, so I just typed those in; then it compiled and ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

"The main() method is not required for JavaFX applications when the JAR file for the application is created with the JavaFX Packager tool, which embeds the JavaFX Launcher in the JAR file. However, it is useful to include the main() method so you can run JAR files that were created without the JavaFX Launcher, such as when using an IDE in which the JavaFX tools are not fully integrated." (Oracle).

Add inside the bottom of your program like just another method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```